# Number of steps to reduce a number to zero leetcode problem

Tags: c, integer-division

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num, count;
    count = 0;
    num = 8;

    while (num != 0)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
        { // checks if num is even
            num = num / 2;
            count = count + 1; // increases counter by 1
        }
        else
        {
            num = num - 1;
            count = count + 1;
        }

        printf("%d", count); // prints counter
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason the output is `1234` instead of `4`, can anyone please explain why? I tried calling `scanf()` instead of setting num value to 8 as well, but the output is the same.

Comment: Close to a typo: the `printf` is **inside** the loop...

Comment: You should take this as a good opportunity to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example a minute stepping through the code statement by statement in a debugger should have shown you the problem.

Comment: A simple typo mistake, your call to `printf()` function is a part of `while` loop, actually in `1234` at last you got `4`.

Comment: It's Karma - you are getting punished by the universe for having such sloppy code formatting. Time to adopt a conventional coding style.

Comment: @Mathieu Don't fix the code formatting on questions where code formatting _is_ the problem! This should be closed as simple typo anyhow, not polished.

Comment: Seriously, I will report the next person who tries to "fix" this post for vandalism. 3 times now, _pay attention to edit history and comments_!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the counter inside a loop and you are not printing it with a newline character.  So you print "1", "2", "3", and then "4" and it looks like "1234" in your terminal.  Use proper indentation so you can see what's going on visually and notice that your `printf` is inside a loop.

Comment: Yeah I confused the brackets, thanks!